# boost shortest path finding algorithm

Tags: c++, boost, graph, path, shortest-path

Good day, dear friends.

I want to find shortest path in random graph. I use boost graph library. As I understand I need to build graph using existing distances between dots. After that I need to use some algorithm...

As I see Dijkstra's algorithm is really finds all paths from 1 point to others. (It should be slow?)

A*  wants some additional data (not only distances)

How can I find the shortest path between 2 points? I saw many shortest path algorithms headers in bgl folder, but I didn't find examples how to use them.

Also I can precompute something for graph is needed.

What should I do?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I used examles from boost graph library. Dijkstra was ok (but slow?). In fact it is only thing that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends on how many nodes you have , as you mentioned your nodes are around O(10^4) and edges are O(10^4) which is good
so in [BOOST LIBRARY DOCS](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/graph/doc/dijkstra_shortest_paths.html) it sasy **The time complexity is O(V log V + E).** so if you put V = 10^4 and E = 10^4 you get about O(10^5) which is very good and can run less than 1 second on a normal computer so you can use it.

A* Algorithm can run faster than Dijkstra but it needs a **heuristic function** which must be **monotonic** and **admissible** and it might be hard to find that function depending on your problem.

so i think Dijkstra would be good enough for your case

Comment: I'll try to test it. Thank you. But I remember that last time Djikstra function searched all paths. Is it me doing something wrong?

Comment: Ohoh. Ok. But I still afraid dijkstra, but I'll try it!

Comment: your graph is small :D !!Don't be afraid! i tried dijkstra on 1million node graph :)

Answer (score 1):

Dijkstra's algorithm takes O(E log(n)) time - where E = #edges and N=#nodes.
It should be fast enough. Please comment on approximate values of E and N.

In some cases (e.g. a Social graph), the following is faster:
- assuming edge weights are 1, N is very large, degree of nodes is small (few hundreds):
Do a 2 level BFS from node1, 2 level BFS from node2 and intersect the sets. If there's a path length of <= 4, you'll find it.

Comment: I want to build graph which represents big building... So... I used 80 nodes in one location... I think it can really be 100 locations... So... Maybe 8000 nodes? Each node usually have 2 edges per node maybe...  Each distance is distance between dots in meters maybe....
Something like this.

Comment: 8000 nodes and 16000 edges - use Dijkstra. No questions asked.